# How to submit few records to approval using script apex?

Tags: apex, approval-process

I've created a script to send multiple records to approval but something is wrong. Script is executed but the records are not submitted. Could someone tell me why ?

```
public void submitForApprovalObject(Object object)
{
    Set<Id> obRecordsToApprove = new Set<Id>{'aaaa','bbbb'};
    Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
    req1.setComments('Submit for approval');
    req1.setObjectId(object.id);
    req1.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {'xxx'}); // Put the approver Id (User Id)
    
    for(Id obRecords : obRecordsToApprove){
        Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would receive errors, because you try to submit the same record for approval multiple times.

Check `Approval.ProcessResult` for it's status

Comment: When I added system.debug('Results: ' + result.getErrors()); 
I don't have any debug logs :(

Comment: So how may I change this script to run submit for few records at once?

Comment: Ok, now it's working as expected. I will close the topic.

Comment: ok, so did I answer you question? If so, please accept my answer and it will close the question. If it's not the case please post your own answer and accept  it